# ¿Por qué el proceso de node.js no finaliza?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo este código en JS que estoy ejectuando con el comando node index.js:

```js
const { createClient } = require('redis');
const client = createClient({
    socket: {
        port: 6379,
        host: "host-goes-here"
    }
});
async function start() {
    console.log('connecting');
    await client.connect();
    console.log('conected');
}

await start()
```

El resultado de ejecutar el código es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El proceso se queda corriendo.

¿Por qué el comportamiento es así? ¿Estoy usando correctamente el `top-level await`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando te conectas usando el `await client.connect();` se abre un hilo para mantener esa conexión pero como nunca lo estas desconectando entonces el proceso no termina.

Prueba con:

```
await client.disconnect();
```

Comment: Probe el módulo redis por casualidad, y no encuentro manera de conectarme, siempre rechaza la conexion, uso createClient() sin parametros y tengo este error: Redis Client Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:6379

Comment: lo instale con npm i redis

Comment: Parece ser un problema de comunicación hacía el server de redis. Para descartar eso podrías usar un cliente de redis externo para validar si te da el mismo error, prueba conectarte con este: https://github.com/qishibo/AnotherRedisDesktopManager